# Where to put a data transfer object used in a Repository class with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, repository, dto

Due to a technical restriction of the entity framework I have to return my data in an extra class which is a data transfer object instead of return the data with a Module class.

```
from m in context.Modules.Where(x => x.ParentId == null)
          join child in context.Modules on m.Id equals child.ParentId
              into groupJoin
          select new ModuleDTO { m.Id, HasChildren = groupJoin.Any() }
```

The ModuleDTO is not my business object. It is used within my ModuleRepository.

Where should I put this DTO object which just holds getter/setter (no logic of course)

Comment: Is ModuleDTO exposed just to repositories, to upper layer or to multiple layers?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka The DTO is returned to my Asp.Net Mvc controller where it is mapped to a viewmodel. So only my ModuleRepository and my ModuleController know the ModuleDTO.

Comment: Why not to place DTO to the same assembly as repository when your controller must reference it anyway?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka I tried this once at I got some unsolvable problem. Now I tried it again and yes thanks it works.